# Fixed-width fonts in iOS?

Tags: ios, fonts

Though my problem is appearently very simple I have a hard time to solve it.
There is (in my app) a label (`UILabel`) that is containing time information (say a clock).
It is updated every second or every fifth of a second. Most of the time only one digit changes.

I want the label contents to look stable (only one digit updating), but it always looks shaky, even though I am trying to use "fixed-width" fonts.

After searching on the net I tried `Courier` and `Menlo-Regular` (supposedly fixed-width) but it still does not work.

Is there no fixed-width font at all in iOS?
If there is which one is it?

Or am I looking in the wrong direction?

Of course I could cut the display into several labels and update only the relevant ones but that seems more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Have you tried setting constraints?

Comment: Do you mind providing any gif or video or demo on what the result is? Since if you use fix-width font, technically it won't be shaky.

Comment: Yes that's right, "if I use fixed-width fonts, it won't be shaky". Therefore since it is shaky, the fonts I am using must not be fix-width. So the question: "Which fonts are fix-width?"